# Showing full image without Cropping part C#

Tags: c#, image

I want to compare two images, where only "date of print" is different, I wanted to crop 'date' area only. But I wanted to show full image without crop area, (not the crop area only)

Code I used for cropping

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\1546.jpg");
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData rawOriginal = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        int origByteCount = rawOriginal.Stride * rawOriginal.Height;
        byte[] origBytes = new Byte[origByteCount];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rawOriginal.Scan0, origBytes, 0, origByteCount);

        //I want to crop a 100x100 section starting at 15, 15.
        int startX = 15;
        int startY = 15;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 100;
        int BPP = 4;        //4 Bpp = 32 bits, 3 = 24, etc.

        byte[] croppedBytes = new Byte[width * height * BPP];

        //Iterate the selected area of the original image, and the full area of the new image
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width * BPP; j += BPP)
            {
                int origIndex = (startX * rawOriginal.Stride) + (i * rawOriginal.Stride) + (startY * BPP) + (j);
                int croppedIndex = (i * width * BPP) + (j);

                //copy data: once for each channel
                for (int k = 0; k < BPP; k++)
                {
                    croppedBytes[croppedIndex + k] = origBytes[origIndex + k];
                }
            }
        }

        //copy new data into a bitmap
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
        BitmapData croppedData = croppedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(croppedBytes, 0, croppedData.Scan0, croppedBytes.Length);

        bmp.UnlockBits(rawOriginal);
        croppedBitmap.UnlockBits(croppedData);

        croppedBitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\AFTERCROP_CROP.jpg");
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\AFTERCROP-ORIG.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Graphics.DrawImage`? As for your question, it doesn't make any sense. Show what? Where? Or do you mean you want to black out a part of a picture, rather than cropping it? `Graphics.FillRectangle` should do the trick.

Comment: yes i want to black out the cropping part.

Comment: That's not what the word `cropping` means

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit overcomplicated, and you seem to be confused about what cropping is - cropping means taking a part of the original picture. What you seem to want instead is to black out some part of the original picture:

[image: Blackout versus cropping]

The easiest way to accomplish this is by drawing a simple filled rectangle over the original image:

```
var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg");

using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 50, 50, 200, 200);
}
```

If you also want to preserve the original bitmap, you can just copy it over.

Comment: Thanks, I did same yesterday in my code, where i need multiple blackout.